# jQuery, если value == ""

Tags: javascript, jquery

правильно ли я переводил скрипт js на jQuery?

```
if(document.querySelector(".input").value == ""){


}

if($(".input").val == ""){

}
```

Comment: val() это метод

Comment: второй раз на одни грабли?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В jquery val это метод, соответственно его нужно вызывать вместе со скобками

```
$(".input").val()
```